# Validar url de Youtube con Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Estimados necesito validar que en un input se introduzca una url de Youtube

```
<input wire:model="video" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Url youtube">
```

Lo que no sé es cómo personalizar una validación personalizada:

Por ejemplo en tiempo real utilizo:

```
$this->validateOnly($field, [ 
    'email' => 'unique:App\User,email|required|email'
]);
```

Y funciona muy bien pero con las reglas de Laravel. Pero para personalizar sé que es distinto pero no encuentro cómo se debe hacer.

Por ejemplo para la url de Youtube, en Stackoverflow encontré la siguiente solución:

[Url Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476060/validating-youtube-url-using-regex)

Que consta de la siguiente función:

```
$rx = '~
  ^(?:https?://)?                           # Optional protocol
   (?:www[.])?                              # Optional sub-domain
   (?:youtube[.]com/watch[?]v=|youtu[.]be/) # Mandatory domain name (w/ query string in .com)
   ([^&]{11})                               # Video id of 11 characters as capture group 1
    ~x';

$has_match = preg_match($rx, $url, $matches);
```

Ahora como puedo implementarlo con Livewire no me doy maña. Que podría hacer?

**EDICIÓN:**

Estoy tratando de hacer algo como esto: Pero me da error la variable $rx

```
$rx = '~
    ^(?:https?://)?                           # Optional protocol
    (?:www[.])?                              # Optional sub-domain
    (?:youtube[.]com/watch[?]v=|youtu[.]be/) # Mandatory domain name (w/ query string in .com)
    ([^&]{11})                               # Video id of 11 characters as capture group 1
        ~x';

    $this->validateOnly($field, [
        'youtube_url' => "regex:$rx",
    ]);
```

**EDICIÓN DOS:**

Estoy probando con una Rules de la siguiente manera:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        preg_match('/https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^&]+/', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'La dirección de Youtube es inválida.';
    }
```

Y pareciera que nunca supera la validación, siempre me muestra el **message** probé cambiando preg_match con diversas reglas que encontré en Google pero no ho funciona.

Al verificar dd($value); siempre llega el valor correcto.

Agradezco mucho una ayuda más.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Gracias @BetaM me había faltado: return (bool)

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/',$value);
```

Comment: El título hace ver a tu pregunta basada en opiniones, recuerda que en el componente lo que es cribes es simple y llano PHP, por lo tanto puedes tener un método vinculado al keydown de un elemento HTML en el cual se evalúe el contenido que vas escribiendo, dicho eso evalúas y lanzas un emit para indicar si la URL tiene o no el patrón solicitado

Comment: Edite el título, gracias. Me pasa que imagino la forma pero no encuentro la manera:  te refieres a usar javascript?

Comment: No necesariamente o no del todo, en cuanto me haga un espacio trataré de responder

Comment: Antes de publicar, puede ser en un comentario pero me gustaría saber cómo intentaste integrar esa expresión regular en tu código

Comment: Hola @BetaM agregué en la edición lo que intento pero aún sigo con dificultad. Se te ocurre otra forma? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debemos tener presente que una de las ventajas de usar **Livewire** es que tenemos de forma *natural* acceso a las bondades de **Laravel**.

Dicho lo anterior, podemos proceder entonces de esta forma:

1. Mueve la lógica de la expresión regular a [**regla de validación personalizada**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)
2. Una vez que en el método `passes` tengas la lógica y en el método `message` describas el texto cuando no se cumpla dicha *regex*, importas tu regla a tu componente de esta forma:

   ```
   use App\Rules\NombreRegla;
   ```
3. Ahora en tu [**validación**](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

   ```
   $this->validate(['regla1', 'regla2', new NombreRegla]);
   ```
4. Puedes considerar meter la validación en un método que es invocado en el evento click asociado a un `button` (*eso ya depende de ti*)

Comment: Primero muchas gracias! Una pregunta antes de llevar a cabo el proceso, en passes agrego solamente la función regular $rx como está en el ejemplo de edición? y entiendo que la url de youtube debe ser enviada a la regla cierto?

Comment: En el método `passes` metes el `preg_macth` y la regex, trata y si no te queda me avisas para agregar a mi respuesta el como queda

Comment: Agregué una edición nueva, disculpa las molestias. Te agradecería mucho tu opinión!! abrazo grande!

Comment: @maraet en el método pases debes hacer un `return` de lo contrario jamás obtendrás el resultado de la expresión regular

Comment: Muchas gracias agregué return (bool)

Comment: Hola @BetaM disculpa las molestias, sabrías cómo puedo hacer que esto sea nullable? la regla me lo hace obligatorio.

Comment: Es decir que no siempre valide?

Comment: Si, el campo no es obligatorio.

Comment: Checa en la doc de Laravel en las reglas de validación puedes pasar nullable para el fin que buscas

Comment: Si pasé la regla de la siguiente manera: 'video' => new RuleYoutube, 'nullable', y me da error: No property found for validation: [0]